# How to interpret print of tensorflow fit with verbosity 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to measure two different ways of loading data and want to compare which one is faster.

First is when I read parquet with pd.read_parquet and second is when reading with pq.pqFile().to_pandas()

when using 1st method and fit tensorflow model it prints

```
Epoch 1/15 
6/Unknown [=============] 169s 194ms/step - loss ....
6/6 [===============] 185s 4s/step - loss....
Epoch 2/15
6/6 [===============] 2s 234ms/step - loss...
Epoch 3/15
6/6 [===============] 2s 224ms/step - loss...
....
```

second method of reading parquet then fitting prints

```
Epoch 1/15 
6/Unknown [=============] 26s 94ms/step - loss ....
6/6 [===============] 28s 108ms/step - loss....
Epoch 2/15
6/6 [===============] 29s 104ms/step - loss...
Epoch 3/15
6/6 [===============] 28s 100ms/step - loss...
....
```

My understanding was first time measurement is time taken for each epoch and 2nd is per batch however if that is the case how come even if 2nd method takes less time per step, total time per epoch is longer?